# There is an error while using System.out.println when both text and variables

Tags: java, oop, class, variables, output

I am a beginner in Java so I wrote a program to understand the OOP concepts but it gives me an error when trying to use System.out.println().
Here's the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sampleClass ADD = new sampleClass();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fNum;
    int sNum;
    System.out.println("Enter the first number to Add");
    fNum = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Now enter the second number");
    sNum = input.nextInt();
    int sum;
    sum = ADD.add(fNum, sNum);
    System.out.println("The sum of " fNum " and " sNum " is " sum);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line `System.out.println("The sum of " fNum " and " sNum " is " sum);` with

```
System.out.println("The sum of " +fNum+ " and " +sNum+ " is " +sum);
```

**Please Note**: *In Java, the operator "+" normally acts as an arithmetic operator unless one of its operands is a String. If necessary it converts the other operand to a String before joining the second operand to the end of the first operand.*

Examples:

If one of the operands is not a String it will be converted:

```
int age = 12; 
 System.out.println("My age is " + age);
```

Comment: @HafizMohammadShayanTariq: Nice.:) . Please donot forget to tick the answer that was helpful to you. It will help the future Visitors.

Answer (score 2):

> Sign "+" is used for concatenation and you missed it between your
>   String.

The correct format is:

> System.out.println("The sum of " + fNum + " and " + sNum + " is " +
>   sum);

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some `+`'s between things like `"The sum of "` and `fNum`, e.g. `"The sum of " + fNum + ....`

Comment: Thanks I've been out of practice for a lot of time and also sleepy.